# json operator(#>>) in JPA native query

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

I have a query which is something like this:

```
...
value::json #>>  '{report, filters, office}' is not null
...
```

which basically searching records in which value contains this json path. My value is of type String hence first i am converting it to json and then applying operator according to this [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-json.html)

But the problem is this query is working fine in potgress but not working when I am using in my spring boot application with JPA native query. Here is my code:

```
StringBuilder queryBuilder = new StringBuilder();
query.append(SOME_ADDITIONAL_STATEMENTS)
.append(" AND (value\\:\\:json #>> :param is not null)")
String queryString = queryBuilder.toString();
query.setParameter("param","'{report, filters, office}'");
List<Object> resultList = query.getResultList();
```

This code is giving me this error:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: json #>> character varying
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

P.S. When i am using like this it is working fine:

```
.append(" AND (value\\:\\:json #>> '{report, filters, office}' is not null)")
```

So i think i am not writing query correctly. Can anyone help please?

Comment: CAST :param to a text array: `CAST(:param AS TEXT[])`

Comment: Thanks @FrankHeikens. One more question, if i want to add array `String[] array = {"report", "filters", "office"};` like this in place of param, how should I do it?

Comment: Sorry, I've been to Java, but I can't program in Java, can't help you with this.